# Can't make shell recursive script work

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to write a recursive function that given a process number, prints out the process numbers of subprocesses spawned from it for up to k generations. The following code does not seem to work, as what I want to do is print it in a sort of tree-like way, where I print the subprocesses of a given process right under it, as opposed to printing the whole generation first, then the second, then so on. What I am trying is more on the spirit of depth first search run through the "graph". Somehow I am not managing to keep track of the levels of recursion to stop at a certain depth. If anyone can spot the mistakes, please let me know.

```
function descendantsRecursive() {
    level=$2
    if [[ "$level" -ge 4 ]]
    then
        exit
    fi
    result=($(pgrep -P "$1" .))
    for pid in "${result[@]}"; do
        echo "$level"
        echo "$pid"
        if [[ "$(pgrep -P $pid)" == '' ]] 
        then
            :
        else
            descendantsRecursive $pid $(( $level+1 ))
        fi
    done
}
```

Comment: Is `echo "$level"` intended to provide indentation?  The added newline will probably be an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The obvious problem is that your variables are global. That doesn't matter for all of them but the fact that level is modified by the call will create a bug.

Furthermore, calling `exit` kills the entire script, and you just want to stop the called function. Use `return`

A good habit is to declare all variables as local:

```
local level=$2 pid result
```

But you could also use fewer variables:

```
function descendantsRecursive() {
    local pid
    if (( $2 >= 4 )); then return; fi
    for pid in $(pgrep -P "$1" .) ; do
        echo "$2"
        echo "$pid"
        # This test is unneeded
        if [[ "$(pgrep -P $pid)" == '' ]] 
        then
            :
        else
            descendantsRecursive $pid $(( $2+1 ))
        fi
    done
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick and to-the-point answer. So if I understand correctly, with level being global, as the function runs down the list of processes it stays at a deeper level even when it's "parsing" more shallow pids.

Comment: @Karl: Without the local declaration, there is only one `$level` for the whole script. Since you only increase it, it never gets smaller. You could also solve the problem by resetting its value after the recursive call finishes, but it is easier to not use the variable at all :)

Comment: @Karl: The reason that the other variables don't matter (in this case) is that you only use `result` once (so it's easy to eliminate), and `pid` is reset after each recursive call (by the `for` statement). However, as I said, trying to deduce which variables matter and which ones don't is a fool's game: make them all local and you won't have these problems.

Comment: Sure, I can totally see your point about the other variables, the script was completely unpolished, but the big news for me was that declaring level like that would make it global across recursion calls. Thanks.

Comment: @karl: perhaps worth noting that local variables are a bash extension. In a basic Posix shell, the only local variables are the positional parameters $1, $2, ...